# validate loaded data in QTableView

Tags: python, delegates, pyqt, tableview

I got a MVC sytle PyQT UI program, and already got delegates binded to certain column for whatever date or regex validation, when insert manually, everything goes fine, the limits holds on

```
class IPDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        line_edit.setValidator(regex_ip)
```

but for loaded data, which I insert by

```
self.model.appendColumn(
    [
        QStandardItem(column_value) 
        for column_value in loaded_line
])
```

such validation only happens when I manually double click inside some table cell，are their any way to check its value automatically? my idea is to loop get focus of each cell, and simulate the 'press enter' operation, to trigger the check, but did not find any similar APIs

any suggestion? 
Thanks, Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by myself, did not use the misery mvc module, turn all data validation to a set of regex, loop over at both set delegate and raw regex validation